# JPA Repository save not saving the list data in input sequence

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called Drink with  id, name, expirationDate. It is treated as a List under Order class.
I have an API call that saves an Order which has List.

Ex:
Drink : first drink, Drink: second drink, etc... the ids are null at this point.

when I call OrderRepository.save(incomingOrder), the drink order comes out different like :
Drink1: id :1 name: second drink, id:2 name first drink etc...

I did check the Rest call and the order of the Drinks is sequential to user's input (e.g. first,second, third etc.) but the saved list is in random order...

I did do a logger output and it seems when the data that I sent to backend is in the order of creation (e.g. firstDrink,secondDrink,thirdDrink etc.), i found out the order of the list changed randomly (secondDrink,thirdDrink,firstDrink) prior to save (at the restController entry point). To fix it would i have to artificially create an id to sort it before save?

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but an ID should not be used to determine business logic, such as using the ID value to determine the record order.  There should be a separate property to explicitly sort.

Comment: no its not to determine record order -it is for the "Drink table" where i have unique records of drinks. They are null prior to input and when saved in the table they have a unique id.   I don't use the id for ordering - it is just the input order is not the same:

I did do a logger output and it seems when the data that I sent to backend is in the order of creation (e.g. firstDrink,secondDrink,thirdDrink etc.), i found out the order of the list changed randomly (secondDrink,thirdDrink,firstDrink) prior to save. To fix it would i have to artificially create an id to sort it before save?

Comment: You would need to dig into the generated SQL to determine why the inserts are in a different order than what you're expecting.  But again, the value of the ID should be irrelevant.

Comment: @user3822558 if you want to preserve order of list elements you need to use [`@OrderColumn`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html)

Comment: but what is it ordering by though? The initial list of data its literally:

Drink : name: firstDrink
Drink : name :secondDrink
Drink: name: thirdDrink
I can't order by the name since they can differ and at that time theres no id to order?
I mean by the time I am in the service to "save", the list is already in a random order...

Comment: There needs to be a column in the database that represents the position of each drink in the order list.